# Select only the most nested list item with specific class

Tags: css, html-lists

I need to select only the the deepest `li.active` in the `ul` structure. In this case that would be `Další kategorie`. I cannot find css only solution. Is it even possible? Thanks.

```
<nav class="smenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="predsednictvo first"><a href="/cs/csmg/predsednictvo/"><span>PŘEDSEDNICTVO</span></a></li>
        <li class="sub active komise"><a href="/cs/csmg/komise/"><span>KOMISE</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="kategorie first"><a href="/cs/csmg/komise/kategorie/"><span>Kategorie</span></a></li>
                <li class="active dalsi-kategorie last"><a href="/cs/csmg/komise/dalsi-kategorie/"><span>Další kategorie</span></a></li> // I'need to select only this element (current page)
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="kontakty"><a href="/cs/csmg/kontakty/"><span>KONTAKTY</span></a></li>
        <li class="reprezentace last"><a href="/cs/csmg/reprezentace/"><span>REPREZENTACE</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't think so, because you're trying to style based not only on the *number* of parents, but based on the element that has the *greatest* number of parents, which requires comparison to parent's sibling-elements. Also, in terms of ancestry, the sibling `li` to `Další kategorie` is equally-deeply nested.

Comment: And assuming that the list has only two levels?

Comment: There is no way you can achieve this with pure css, atleast not without affecting the li items in between. You can use something like jquery which'll make this fairly simple.

Comment: @actimel If you know the number of levels then this can be done.

Comment: @Jeevan Jose - even if I don't know if the deepest .active class is in the first or second level? And you didn't mention how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
This is currently not possible only via CSS. Children cannot affect thei parents. It will be possible once CSS4 `:has()` selector gets from working draft to specification and browsers starts implementing it. Current state: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational

---

**Original answer:**
Ok, if it's not possible only via CSS, that's how I would do it:

```
$('li.active:not(:has(li.active))').addClass('deepest');
```

Answer (score 0):

When it is static structure then this selector should do the job:

```
.smenu > ul > li > ul > li.active {
    /* your rules */
}
```

Comment: No, it's not static. That's the problem. It's navigation and its HTML structure cannot be changed. It's necessary to select li.active in first level, if it's active and has no child with .active class.

Comment: hm, when the structure is dynamic i also think it´s not possible with pure css. You could do with javascript/jquery and go recursivly over the elements and select only the deepest.

Comment: here some information:
[link 1](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3622321/Javascript-Basics-Part-12.htm)

[link 2](http://blog.swapnilsarwe.com/javascript-traversing-html-dom-recursively.html)

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
nav.smenu ul li ul li.active
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing additional detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this was available at the time of the OP, but this works just as well as the accepted answer without the `:has` operator:

```
$('.smenu').find('li.active').last().addClass('deepest')
```

Assuming only one nested path is active at once.